# How to see a Clojure function's call hierarchy using Eclipse and CounterClockwise

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I am new to Clojure and try to read open source Clojure code using CounterClockwise and eclipse. One issue makes my progress slow is that I don't know how to find out a Clojure function's call hierarchy (something like "open call hierarchy" in Java which displays methods that invoke the selected method) using CounterClockwise. What I am doing now is use eclipse's text search but this is inconvenient.

any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that's not possible in Eclipse / Counterclockwise. It works in [Cursive](http://cursiveclojure.com/userguide/) (IntelliJ based Clojure IDE), and is called 'Find Usages' (Alt-F7).